# Customize WooCommerce Add To Cart Form Name

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I've created Google Tag Manager and Google Analytics process to capture the Form Name in an Event across the site. For WooCommerce, there's no form name on an **Add To Cart** form, though. Here's what it looks like:

`<form class="cart" action="[PRODUCT URL]" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

I'd like to update that line of code to:
`<form class="cart" action="[PRODUCT URL]" name="Add [PRODUCT NAME] To Cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

I can't find the form anywhere in the WooCommerce templates within the theme to modify the form name, though. Is there a filter that can be applied?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it using the override woocommerce template.

Guide to override template - https://zemez.io/support/wordpress/how-to/override-woocommerce-template-files/

Once you copy templates/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php to your child theme, you can edit simple.php and add form name.